# Using Anaconda and Spyder, I keep getting SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, syntax, spyder, anaconda

I'd been running code on my Windows desktop using Anaconda and 3.3.1. All good. Everything works.

When I tried running it on my laptop (also Windows, running the same versions), I keep getting SyntaxError: invalid syntax for anything I write. For example:

```
print ("Hello World")

>>> runfile(r'C:\Users\Laptopname\Desktop\.temp.py', wdir=r'C:\Users\Laptopname\Desktop')
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    runfile(r'C:\Users\Laptopname\Desktop\.temp.py', wdir=r'C:\Users\Laptopname\Desktop')
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

When I run it in IDLE, however, it works fine.

There's something wrong, I think, with the settings on Spyder. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This is not an answer, only an extended comment:*

Open up a python interactive interpreter and type

```
with open(r'C:\Users\Laptopname\Desktop\.temp.py', 'rb') as f:
    print(repr(f.read()))
```

Please post the output. (This will show us *exactly* what is in the file.)

Comment: ok, I think I know what the problem is...my "Laptopname" actually has an apostrophe in it, as in John's Laptop, so the path is technically C:\Users\John. Just going to create a new username and go from there. Thanks!